# Prove that limit doesn't exists at all

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which I have proved that $\lim_{x \to0^+}f(x)=\infty$, and I need to prove that $\lim_{x \to0^+}f'(x) \ne -\infty$.

I have got that $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$

I am trying to prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}$$

Does not equal to $-\infty$ (or to prove that it doesn't exists at all).

I have tried to assume by contradiction that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}=-\infty$$

So there exists $\delta_{1}>0$ such that for every $0<x<\delta_{1}$ we say that $$f(x)<\square $$

We choose $\delta=\delta_{1}$, and let $0<x<\delta$ so:

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}(1+\cos(\frac{1}{x}))\le -\frac{2}{x^2}<\frac{2}{\delta^2}=k$$

I do not know what to choose instead of $\square$, and if what I did is correct.

Appreciate your help!

**I have also tried to think about the continuity of $f$, and saying that it is not bounded so it can't be continuous, so the limit doesn't exists.**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Big hint - $\cos(\pi+2k\pi) =-1$ for all $k$

Comment: I have try thinking about if for a while, but I do not know what to do with your hint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrap the whole proof by contradiction thing, it's not necessary.

**Hint:** Find the values of $x$ such that $\frac{1}{x} = 2k\pi$, and $\frac{1}{x} = (2k+1)\pi,$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Edit: In fact, as Calvin Khor pointed out in the comments to this answer, you only need one of the above two sequences to show that $\lim_{x \to0^+}f'(x) \ne -\infty$, which was the original question.

Further edit: I think OP doesn't properly understand what is meant by $lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$. I also needed a sanity check, which is why I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987809/equivalent-definitions-of-lim-x-to-cgx-infty/3987823?noredirect=1#comment8229100_3987823).

If $g(x)$ is a real function, then a definition of $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$ is:

> for each $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $x \in (c,c+\delta) \implies g(x) < \gamma$.

So an equivalent definition of $\ \neg\left(\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty\ \right) $ is:

> there exists $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there exists $x'\in(c,c+\delta)$ with $g(x')\ge \beta$

If no such $\beta$ exists, then $\ \lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty\ .$

Note that $g$ need not be continuous at $c$ in either of my definitions.

Comment: Your hint gives one way to show its not convergent, but you need only the second half to show that it does not converge to $-\infty$

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by finding $x$'s values?

Comment: What do you think about showing that $f'$ isn't bounded? By choosing $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x=\frac{1}{\pi +2 \pi n}$?

Comment: $k$ represents an integer (other than $0$). Do you know how to rearrange equations? And do you know what the graph of $\cos$ looks like? Then you should try to draw the graph of $\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ using my hint.

Comment: Yeah I used your hint to think about that of course!

Comment: "What do you think about showing that $f′$ isn't bounded?" You're asked to show that $f'\nrightarrow-\infty$. Showing that $f'$ isn't bounded doesn't show that $f'\nrightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: If $f$ isn't bounded, than it's not continuous, so the limit doesn't exists

Comment: I thought we were talking about $f'$, not $f$ ?

Comment: Yes, $f'$, sorry

Comment: Well what was the original question? To show that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x)\neq -\infty$, or to show that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: To show that the limit $\ne - \infty$

Comment: Ah, I think you don't properly understand what is meant by $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it!

Comment: I will add onto the end anyway. Continuity had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you! Please look at my answer below :)

Comment: See also a question I just posted, asking for a sanity check: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987809/equivalent-definitions-of-lim-x-to-cgx-infty

Answer (score 4):

Because there exists a subsequence converging to $0$:

if you pick $\{x_k\}$ to be such that $x_k=\frac{1}{\pi + 2\pi k}$, then
$$f^\prime (x_k) = -(\pi + 2\pi k)^2 \Big(1+cos(\pi + 2\pi k)\Big) = 0,$$
since
$$cos(\pi + 2\pi k)=-1 \mbox{, } \forall k;$$
Also the sequence of $x_k$ converges to $0$ as you can observe letting $k\to +\infty$.

Comment: Beat you to it by about 20 seconds. I'm getting quicker at this.

Comment: Lol, I'm cool with taking my time.

Comment: Why can I choose this $x$? What is the benefit of showing that $f'(x_{k})=0$?

Comment: If you apply the definition of limit knowing this you see it doesn't work. The idea is that you always have an $x_k$ for some $k$ such that it is as close to $0^+$ as you want, so the limit can't be $-\infty$: in particular this shows that, if it exists, it is $0$.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

With $z:=\dfrac1x$, rewrite as

$$\lim_{z\to\infty}-z^2(1+\cos z).$$

Then it is clear that the function alternates between $0$ and $-2z^2$.

Comment: Why is it clear?

Comment: @MathLover: do you really need a tutorial on the cosine function ?

Comment: No, I know that $cos(?)$ is between -1 and 1, but $-z^2 \to -\infty$ so I do not understand why is it clear...

Comment: @MathLover: isn't $1+\cos z$ between $0$ and $2$ ?

Comment: It is, yes. But then the limit is $-\infty$ or I missed something

Comment: @MathLover: does $0$ tend to infinity ?

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: @GuyPago: mh, it differs in every sentence I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:**

You can try making it a bit "easier" by substitution.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{cos(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}\underset{t=\frac{1}{x}}{\Rightarrow}$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}-t^{2}\left(1+\cos t\right)$$
Now it should be easier to negate by definition, as you can easily see that no matter how big $t$ is, and how small $f'$ is for those big $t$'s, you can choose $t<t_1$ such that $f'(t_1)=0$

If you'll still be struggling, make sure to leave a comment and I will help you further.

**Part 2:**

Assuming, in contradiction that $\lim_{t\to\infty}-t^{2}\left(1+\cos t\right)=-\infty$

Then there exists $M_{1}<0$ such that for every $t<M_{1}$ we have:$$f\left(t\right)<-1$$
Choosing $M_{1}>t_{1}=\lfloor M_{1}\rfloor\cdot2\pi-\pi$ , we get: $$f\left(t\right)=0>-1$$ Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you for that, I have already tried it before actually...

Comment: Look at the edit

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

Assume by contradiction that for every $K<0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $0<x<\delta$, we get $f'(x)<K$.

We choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>K$, and we choose $x_{n}= \frac{1}{\pi +2 \pi n}$.

Note that $0<\frac{1}{\pi +2 \pi n}<1$. (So in this case $\delta=1$)

And: $f'(x)=-(\pi +2\pi n)(\cos(\pi+2\pi n)+1)=0>K$

So $f'(x)>K$, in contradiction!

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first line, "Assume by contradiction that there exists $K<0$ such that $f'(x)<K$", is meaningless. Do you mean: Assume by contradiction that there exists $K<0$ such that $f'(x)<K $ for all $x$ ? Or: Assume by contradiction that there exists $K<0$ such that $f'(x)<K$ for all $ x>c$? Or something else?

Comment: I meant $x>0$ not $x>c$.

Comment: That for every $\delta>0$ there exists $0<x<1$, in this case, $\delta=1$ and we chose $x$ to be $x_{n}$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you think you should edit your answer then please do so.

Comment: I have edited the answer :) Thanks a lot for your time my friend!

Comment: Now your first sentence is poorly-worded. And if instead you meant: Assume there exists $K<0$ such that for every $\delta>0,\ 0<x<\delta \implies f'(x)<K$. Then this is the same as saying: Assume that $\{f'(x):x>0\}$ is bounded above by $K$. This is irrelevant to what you're trying to prove. You also, don't need $K<0$ in all of this, you could just write $K \in \mathbb{R}.$ Try again.

Comment: I've slightly edited the definitions in my answer. Please have a look now and see if it makes any more sense than before.

Comment: I do not understand why is it irrelevant? If the function $\to -\infty$, than for every $K<0$ the function will be below it. But, I have showed that there exists such a $K$ which the limit definition doesn't hold...

Comment: "for every $K<0$ the function will be below it". Ah, but that's not what you said in your answer. You said, *there exists $K<0...$"

Comment: What would make sense is if you wrote: Assume by contradiction that for each $K\in \mathbb{R},\ $ there exists $ \delta>0$ such that for every $0<x<\delta$, we get $f'(x)<K$.  This does mean the same as: $\lim_{x \to0^+}f'(x) = -\infty$ Maybe this is what you meant to write?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Will that be legit? Can I assume that?

Comment: I have edited the answer again to your correction

Comment: Yeah but then I'm not sure about the rest of your answer. It's convoluted. Writing, "We choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>K$" is redundant: we know this is going to be true because $K<0<n.$ I would write: Assume by contradiction that for *each* $K<0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $0<x<\delta$, we get $f'(x)<K$. Choose $n > \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\pi\delta} - 1 \right).\ $ Then $\ 0<\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+2n\right)} < \delta$ and $f'\left(\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+2n\right)}\right) = 0 > K.$ Contradiction.

Comment: Adam, thank you so much for your time! You helped me a lot! I appreciate that!

Comment: sure, no problem. Limit definitions are fiddly and can be confusing, so requires lots of care.

Comment: Yeah you are right :)