# Equivalent definitions of $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987477/prove-that-limit-doesnt-exists-at-all/3987481#3987481), I originally wrote in my answer:

> Further edit: I think OP doesn't properly understand what is meant by
> $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$.
>
> If $g(x)$ is a function, then $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty$ means
> that, for each $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}, \exists \delta > 0 $ such that
> $x \in (c,c+\delta) \implies g(x) < \gamma$.
>
> So an equivalent definition of $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) \neq -\infty\ $
> is:
>
> $\exists \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: for each $x > c, \exists x'\
> > $ with $\ c<x'<x$ such that $g(x') > \beta.$
>
> If no such $\beta$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty\ .$
>
> Note that $g$ need not be continuous at $c$ in either of my
> definitions.

The first line is ironic because now it is me asking for a sanity check, so my answer is a little bit of the blind leading the blind, or rather, the slightly confused leading the (probably) more confused. Anyway are my definitions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definition for
$\displaystyle
\lim_{x\to c+}g(x)=-\infty
$ is okay.

But people usually don't use an expression such as $\displaystyle
\lim_{x\to c+}g(x)\ne-\infty
$,
the meaning of which is ambiguous, and it does not convey much information. One can simply say something like "$\displaystyle
\lim_{x\to c+}g(x)=-\infty
$ is not true", which is the same as saying:

> there exists $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\delta>0$, there exists $x'\in(c,c+\delta)$ with $g(x')\ge \beta$.

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: Would the following line make sense as a definition of $\neg\left(\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty\ \right)$:$$$$ $\exists \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: for each $x > c, \exists x'\
 $ with $\ c<x'<x$ such that $g(x') > \beta.$ $$$$
And if no such $\beta$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to c^+}g(x) = -\infty\ .$

Comment: @AdamRubinson: that is okay. I would simply write the negation of the definition of $\lim_{x\to c+}g(x)=-\infty$ using what has been written.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I also think our definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: that's correct.